# Call a simple textview when pushed the info button in Xcode

Tags: xcode4.5

I have made a infobutton in my app, and the code in viewdidload look like this:

```
UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
[infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showInfo:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                       initWithCustomView:infoButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButtonItem;
```

But how do i add a simple textview to this info button, so when i pushed it the text will appear?

I tryed to look in the NavBar sample code from apple, but i haven't manage to get it to work.

Can anyone help me?

Edit:

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Untested, as I don't have a Mac nearby, but... you if you create the textView in a shared object, you should be able to set its text within the showInfo: selector and declare it visible.

Comment: I am a little bit new to this, do you mean that i create a new object with a textview in the main .m file and then i can call the text in a showinfo selector and make it visible?